# How to 'GROUPT BY' after 'ORDER BY' in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using the following query to get a list of users having maximum 'speed'.

With group by:

```
SELECT users.email, speed.speed 
  FROM users INNER JOIN speed ON users.email=speed.email 
  GROUP BY users.email 
  ORDER BY speed.speed DESC LIMIT 15
```

[image]

How ever on running the query, the 'ORDER BY' is not working. It always show the result in the top.

If I remove 'GROUP BY', I got the order list. But I only want 1 row with same email ids. How can i apply group by on this?

Without Group By:

```
SELECT users.email, speed.speed 
  FROM users INNER JOIN speed ON users.email=speed.email 
  ORDER BY speed.speed DESC LIMIT 15
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an aggregate function, GROUP BY will show you the grouped column with whichever value is selected last from non-grouped columns. You'll want to use an aggregate function on your speed.speed column if you want it sorted.

If you want each user with their maximum speed you'll want to do something like

`SELECT users.email, MAX(speed.speed) FROM users INNER JOIN speed ON users.email=speed.email ORDER BY speed.speed DESC LIMIT 15`

Or if you wanted the minimum

`SELECT users.email, MIN(speed.speed) FROM users INNER JOIN speed ON users.email=speed.email ORDER BY speed.speed DESC LIMIT 15`

Or Both

`SELECT users.email, MAX(speed.speed) as maxspeed, MIN(speed.speed) as minspeed FROM users INNER JOIN speed ON users.email=speed.email ORDER BY speed.speed DESC LIMIT 15`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the 15 highest speeds:

```
SELECT s.email, s.speed
FROM speed s
ORDER BY s.speed DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

If you want the users with the highest speed:

```
SELECT s.email, s.speed
FROM speed s
WHERE s.speed = (SELECT MAX(s2.speed) FROM speed s2)
LIMIT 15;
```

Note that joins are not needed for these queries.